# Function parameter - array default value | best practice

Tags: php, arguments

What is the best practice for defining a default/fallback value for an array?

**description:**

My function accepts 2 parameters. One of them is an array of options to choose from. If the array hasn't been passed, it has a default/fallback value as in example:

```
public function selectName($howMany = 1, $seed = ['john', 'bob', 'mark', 'cindy']){...
```

*supporting questions:*

a) Is storing *filled* array in default arguments a good idea?

b) Which would be better, a constant, `array_merge`, `if(empty...`?

Comment: This depends on the scenario, you are essentially asking what is better: merging the arrays or redefining it. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @George I think you understood correctly. Main question would be: is storing an array with values as default function parameter a good idea. If now - which solution would work best?

Comment: There's nothing *wrong* with having your default values up in the parameter definitions, it just might have drawbacks you don't want. Again, scenario specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the default values are shared with all of your objects, it is better to decalre them as `static`.
Reducing the visibility to `protected` is recommended

```
class YourClass {
    protected static $_DEFAULT_SEED     = array('john', 'bob', 'mark', 'cindy');
    protected static $_DEFAULT_QUANTITY = 1;
    public function selectName($howMany = NULL, $seed = NULL){
        if (is_null($howMany)) {
            $howMany    = self::$_DEFAULT_QUANTITY;
        }
        if (is_null($seed)) {
            $seed       = self::$_DEFAULT_SEED;
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: i would add if (is_null($seed) **|| !is_array($seed)**) .... but solution get upvote from me

Comment: @donald123 change it and i will approuve it :), to stay coherent we should add : `if (is_null($seed) || !is_integer($seed))` ...

Answer (score 1):

Better you pass an empty array as argument.

```
public function selectName($howMany = 1, $seed = array()){
    $myarr=['john', 'bob', 'mark', 'cindy'];
    if(count($seed)>0){
        $myarr=$seed;
    }
    /* user $myarr now*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i would do so. In such case you can set only that params, you want to change

```
function f($array = null) {
   $params = array('a' => '1', 'b' => '2');    // default params
   if ($array) $params = array_replace($params, $array);
   foreach($params as $k => $v)
     echo "$k => $v \n";
}

f();  // a => 1  b => 2 
f(array('b' => "new")); // a => 1 b => new
```

Comment: Instead of if ($array) { ... }  use if ( is_array ( $array ) ) { ... } to avoid problems

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, storing the filled array in default arguments isn't a good idea. What if you call the function with an array that has not every key you need?

**Example:**

You want

```
(default): ['option1' => true, 'option2' => false]
You call the function with: ['option1' => true]
```

Now you call the function with an array, but not with enough keys. So in my opinion, array_merge() is the best solution here.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, I pass the array values directly in the function

```
<?php
public function selectName($howMany = 1, $seed = false){
  $seed = (!$seed) ? array('john', 'bob', 'mark', 'cindy') : $seed;
  // rest of the job ... 
}
```

Or if the array is used in several functions, I pass it in a class CONSTANT like this

```
CONST SEED_DEFAULT_VALUE = array('john', 'bob', 'mark', 'cindy');

public function selectName($howMany = 1, $seed = false){
  $seed = (!$seed) ? self::SEED_DEFAULT_VALUE : $seed;
  // rest of the job ... 
}
```

Comment: Arrays are not allowed as constants

Comment: @JordiMartín till php >= 5.6 you can use arrays see http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php